# How to deserialize xml in Django?

Tags: django

I am sorry maybe for the stupid question, I read [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/serialization/) about serialize and deserialize, but i can't get how to deserialize xml data to the model. For example, I have model that look like:

```
class XMLData(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
   description = models.CharField()
```

And my xml data looks like this:

```
<Root>
   <Product>
      <name>Name1</name>
      <description>Description1</description>
   </Product>
   <Product>
      <name>Name2</name>
      <description>Description2</description>
   </Product>
</Root>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for obj in serializers.deserialize("xml", data):
    do_something_with(obj)
```

As mentioned in the docs, so you just read your xml and put in the "data" variable.
the way you read your xml depends on your implementation.

Comment: I understand this and I did that, but how to put `obj` in my model?

Comment: you only have to call obj.save()  where the obj is the obj above or what ever you call it.